# React-native-android - How to save an image to the Android file system and view in the phone's 'Gallery'

Tags: filesystems, react-native, react-native-fs, react-native-fetch-blob

Is it possible to save an image to the android's local file system so it can be viewed from the phone's 'Gallery' and in a folder??

I found this [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) library but after studying the documentation and working through an example I am still unsure if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, here is the solution.

## Solution

I am using the [File System API](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API) from the [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) library. This is because I tought it was way better documented and easier to understand than the 'react-native-fs' library.

I request an image from the server, receive a base64 and I then save it to the Pictures directory in the android fs.

I save the image like this:

```js
var RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob').default;

const PictureDir = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.PictureDir;

getImageAttachment: function(uri_attachment, filename_attachment, mimetype_attachment) {

   return new Promise((RESOLVE, REJECT) => {

   // Fetch attachment
   RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', config.apiRoot+'/app/'+uri_attachment)
   .then((response) => {

     let base64Str = response.data;

     let imageLocation = PictureDir+'/'+filename_attachment;

     //Save image
     fs.writeFile(imageLocation, base64Str, 'base64');
     console.log("FILE CREATED!!")

     RNFetchBlob.fs.scanFile([ { path : imageLocation, mime : mimetype_attachment } ])
     .then(() => {
       console.log("scan file success")
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log("scan file error")
     })

    }).catch((error) => {
    // error handling
    console.log("Error:", error)
  });
},
```

The following code that is in the above method refreshes the Gallery otherwise the images would not display untill the phone is turned off and back on again.

```js
RNFetchBlob.fs.scanFile([ { path : imageLocation, mime : mimetype_attachment } ])
.then(() => {
  console.log("scan file success")
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("scan file error")
})
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Do you know why binary always is text (base64) in React-Native? I don't get it. I don't understand programming for mobile, but I doubt Android only handles text files. Nor is Javascript limited to textfiles. So why can't I save BINARY files?

Comment: Hello. I got the error "RNFetchBlob.scanFile is not a function"
And file stored successful. But I can't view the file on photo booth. My devices is ios simulator :/

Answer (score 12):

You can absolutely do this with [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs).  There's a [`PicturesDirectoryPath`](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=picturesdirectorypath) constant which isn't mentioned in the README for the project; if you save a file into there it should appear in the Gallery app.  If you want it to appear in your own album, just make a new directory in that folder and save the file into there, eg

```js
const myAlbumPath = RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath + '/My Album'

RNFS.mkdir(myAlbumPath)
  .then(/* write/copy/download your image file into myAlbumPath here */)
```

I don't have full example code anymore sorry, because I ended storing images in my app's private cache directory instead. Hope this helps anyway!

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go and see what what happens.

Comment: Hey. I am still having a lot of trouble with react-native-fs. Could you please have a look at this question if you get a chance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662309/how-to-save-pdf-to-android-file-system-react-native